# Is the 'spec' command deprecated in rspec2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I ask this because typing spec returns this error..

```
 ..ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:335:in `bin_path': can't find executable spec for rspec-2.0.0.beta.17 (Gem::Exception)
```

But 'rspec' seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are correct - I have the same behaviour, and the documentation uses 'rspec' as well (http://rdoc.info/projects/rspec/rspec-core).